# Robolectric-2.3 testing animation

Tags: android, animation, robolectric

I'm writing test to my project with Robolectric-2.3.

I'd like to test my UI properties such as Views visibility. The actions of showing/hiding views are wrapped into Animations. **How to test it ?**

I tried to use ShadowSystemClock.sleep() method to wait until animation ends but it doesn't seem to work as I expected.

```
@Test
public void testHideSearch() throws Exception {
    mListFragment.hideSearch();   //<--- animation launched here
    sleep(1000);
    View searchEditText = mListFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.filterEditText);
    assertFalse(searchEditText.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**What is the correct approach to the issue ?**

Answer (score 2):

Try using this instead of sleep:

```
Robolectric.getUiThreadScheduler.advanceBy(1000);
```

Comment: i tested this one, was really looking forward to it, but resolut was:
CurrentTime: 1:0:34:034 
CurrentTime after 2000ms advanceBy…: 1:0:34:034 
(didn't work)

Comment: Update:  `Robolectric.getForegroundThreadScheduler().advanceBy(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`

Answer (score -1):

If you use Animator's your approach should work, but if you use Animations, you'll need to use ShadowAnimation instead.  Assuming the actual visibility of your view is changed in onAnimationEnd(), something like the following should work:

```
ShadowAnimation animation = Robolectric.shadowOf(searchEditText.getAnimation());
animation.invokeEnd();
```

Comment: Running Robolectric 3.0, I get "error no suitable method found for shadowOf(Animation)"

Comment: The OP asked about Robolectric 2.3